# In order to find $n$ unknowns why do we need $n$ equations (non linear case)

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

As indicated by the title, why do we need at least $n$ equations (linearly independent?) to find $n$ unknowns?

Does this rule differ between linear case and non-linear case?

I found this related question: [Necessary condition for uniqueness solution in a system of non-linear equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693598/necessary-condition-for-uniqueness-solution-in-a-system-of-non-linear-equations?rq=1)   , however I am asking about the existance of a solution and not the uniqueness.

**Edit** : **To make my quetsion more specific**:  I am having $n$ unknowns $x_1, \cdots, x_n $ and a generating equation  $ f(x_1, \cdots, x_n,t)= 0$.  $f$ here is a polynomial in $x_1, \cdots, x_n,t$. As the   function $f$ depends on $t$, so if  I change  $t$   I  get a new equation involving  $x_1, \cdots, x_n $.  I want to  find the values of  these $n$ knowns. So how many equations I need ( generated from varying $t$ in $f$) to gauranre a solution  for  $x_1, \cdots, x_n $ .

Giving some references in this manner would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question can be answered on many different levels. In one end of the spectrum you have things like [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), and in the other end you have simple insertion and appeal to intuition. What is your level?

Comment: @Arthur I have basic idea about algebra, so i prefer to have a "simple simple insertion and appeal to intuition ".

Comment: I would be happy to know  why my question is downvoted, so that I avoid  same mistakes next time.

Comment: `I found this is related, however I am asking about the existance of a solution and not the uniqueness` You may want to clarify that further. Existence of solutions is a far lower bar, and doesn't really `find n unknowns` but rather implies that solutions do exist. For example (the linear) $a x +  b y = 0$ has infinitely many solutions $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, and so does the (non-linear) $x^2-y^2=0$, while the (non-linear) $x^2+y^2=0$ has a unique solution (per the posted link). What exactly is your question?

Comment: @dxiv sorry for this ambiguity in my question. I edited it trying to make it  more clear.

Comment: @Nizar The answer depends on the particular $f\,$, as pointed out in other comments and answers already.

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to prove rigoruosly, but here is an intuitive idea, based on the notion that a single equation with more than one variable has too many solutions for our taste, a single equation in one unknown has a good number of solutions, while several equations in a single variable has too few solutions (usually none).

Say we have our equations
$$
\cases{f_1(x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots,x_n) = 0\\
f_2(x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots,x_n) = 0\\
f_3(x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots,x_n) = 0\\
\vdots\\
f_m(x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots,x_n) = 0
}
$$
Now, we solve the first equation with respect to $x_1$ to get something of the form $x_1 = g_1(x_2, x_3,\ldots,x_n)$ (in other words, we get $x_1$ alone on one side, and no $x_1$'s on the other side). This we can now insert into all the other equations. We have now used the first equation, so it is useless as far as solving the system goes (it tells us what $x_1$ is once we've solved all the others, but there are no $x_1$ in the other equations left, so it doesn't tell us anything that helps with the other equations).

Thus we've used up one equation to eliminate one variable. We can keep going, using one equation to eliminate one variable until we get to the last one. Now, if $m<n$, then we are on the last equation, we've used all the others, but we still have more than one variable left. Thus the system has too many solutions for our taste. If, on the other hand, $n<m$, then we are left with several equations, all in one variable, which is not good either. We are left with the case $m = n$, in which case we are left with one equation with one variable, which is exactly what we wanted.

Note about non-linearity: If, say, the first equation is non-linear, then there might be several solutions for $x_1$. In other words, there might be several $g_1$'s that solve the equation. In that case you split the system of equations into one for each $g_1$. For instance, if the first equation is quadratic, so you get two solutions, then you end up with two different sets of $m-1$ equations in $n-1$ unknowns. They should be solved separately.

Also, introducing higher degrees makes it possible that you have no solutions, even though the equations are independent and there are as many equations as there are unknowns. This is just like a regular one-variable equation in higher degree. For instance
$$
\cases{x^2 + y^2 = 1\\
x^2 - y = 2}
$$
has no solutions. On the other hand, if you change that last equation's right-hand side to $= 1.1$, you get four solutions, if you change it to $= 1$ you get three solutions, if you change it to $= 0$ you get two solutions, and if you change it to $= -1$ you get one solution.

Comment: to clarify; these rules apply to equations of all degrees, and the statements of the kind "too many equations and too few variables lead to no solutions" are not always true, but are taken to be general based on probability. Have I got it right?

Comment: @HarryHolmes Yeah, more or less. The theory behind exactly when the different edge cases happen is pretty rich and there have been books written on the subject. But as a general intuition that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as the intersection of hyper-surfaces. To begin with keep it simple and stick to the linear case in 2-d. So two unknowns and two equations. Each equation defines a line in a 2-d space. At some point they will intersect and this point is the solution. (If the lines are parallel then the equations are not independent and hence no solution.)
Now if the equations were non-linear then they may not intersect, and hence no solution can be found.

Going back to the linear case but now in three dimensions. An equation now defines a plane in 3-d space. Two planes will intersect to give a line. The third plane will intersect this line to give a point which is the solution.
In higher dimensions its just more of the same.

Comment: Should I understand that in the nonlinear case  the condition "number of equation is at least n"  is not a necessary condition? neither a sufficient ?

Comment: Say you have two curves given by non-linear equations A and B. If they do not intersect consider adding another equation C, and assume C intersects both A. Where C intersects curve A is a solution to the two equations A & C but there is absolutely no information from equation B  in this solution so you have not gained anything other then solving a different system. You need one equation for each unknown. Too few equations leave you with a surface of a curve not a point. Too many equations  and if there is a solution some equations won't contribute.