# How many equations are required to solve $n$ many variables?

Tags: problem-solving, nonlinear-system

If we have consistent system of ***linear*** equations, each of which has variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, then we will require having $n$ many equations in order to find the one-true single solutions set for all those $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ variables.

***My question is:***  What if the equations were nonlinear?  Then, how many of them would we need to solve the $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$?

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693598/necessary-condition-for-uniqueness-solution-in-a-system-of-non-linear-equations?rq=1) but it does not give any crisp answer.  E.g. it does not say whether $>n$ equations can be necessary for some kind of $n$-variabled equations.

Comment: "*whether $>n$ equations can be necessary*" $\;$ For a single variable example, $\sin(x)=0$ and $\cos(\sqrt{2}\, x)=1$ both have infinitely many solutions, but as a system the solution $x=0$ is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to the linear case, that depends quite heavily on what kind of  numbers you accept as a solution!

Let's deal with the case of real or rational numbers first. Then a *single* equation can be sufficient for any number of variables: you will find that $x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 = 0$ has exactly one solution over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.

Over the complex numbers, things are a bit different - since the field of complex numbers is algebraically closed, we find that for $n$ variables, we need at least $n$ equations. Proving this is quite a bit more difficult than in the linear case, though, and requires heavy tools from commutative algebra.

In general, this kind of question is the starting point for studying Algebraic Geometry; the specific question is tackled as part of dimension theory.

*Edit*: in response to the edit - this is a non-trivial question. There are examples where more than n equations are required - the key word is "incomplete intersection "

*Edit*: Here's an example of a system of three equations in two variables where any two equations do not determine a unique point:
$$
\begin{align}
x \cdot y = 0\\
x \cdot (x+y) = 0\\
y \cdot (x+y) = 0
\end{align}
$$
All three systems combined have a single solution, $x = y = 0$. The first and second allow for $x = 0$, $y$ arbitrary, the first and third for $y = 0$, $x$ arbitrary, and the second and third for any $x, y$ such that $x + y = 0$.

*Edit*: A bit more detail.

My idea in constructing the example was to find three polynomials in two variables so that for any two of them, their zero sets would have a component in common. To keep things simple, I chose to pick three polynomials whose zero sets were unions of lines, like this:
[image]

Now, as noted in the comments, if $p$ has zero set $P$ and $q$ has zero set $Q$, $p \cdot q$ has zero set $P \cup Q$, so it's fairly easy to derive the equations of the three graphs in question (just compute the equations of each line in turn, and multiply).

This generalizes easily: let $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ be polynomials such that for $i \neq j$ $p_i$ and $p_j$ have exactly one common solution, and each $p_i$ has infinitely many zeros. Define $q_i := p_1 \ldots p_{i-1} \cdot p_{i+1} \cdots p_k$; this gives a set of $k$ polynomials such that any $k-1$ have at least two solutions, but the entire set has at most one.

There is a lot more that can be said here, but at this point, the best course of action is to go and read an introduction to Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: Are there cases where $n$ variables require more than $n$ equations?

Comment: Could you please add one example of "incomplete intersection"?  (Re: edit)

Comment: @caveman done. I actually had to sit down and draw the solutions sets I wanted to intersect, hence the delay.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Any link that shows which kind of drawings are these?  Also any idea how far can we go to increase the gap between number of variables and number of required equations?

Comment: I'll add more details to the answer later, but the approach is pretty simple: let $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ be polynomials in $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. Denote by $V_K(p_1, \ldots, p_k) := \{ \vec{x} \in K^n | p_1(\vec{x}) = \ldots = p_k(\vec{x}) = 0 \}$. Then we have $V_K(p, q) = V_K(p) \cap V_K(q)$, and $V_K(p \cdot q) = V_K(p) \cup V_K(q)$. So you can simply pick an arbitrary number of polynomials $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ (with some side conditions to ensure there are no common components) and just consider the products $q_i := (p_1 \cdots p_n) / p_i$.

Comment: @caveman More detail added, enjoy.

Comment: http://codepad.org/1zYe9lJg - tried with non-zero and failed.  Thoughts?

Comment: I would recommend always working with equations of the form $p=0$ - all the theory is set up around that. What effect were you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to see if I can define a set of operations for a symmetric block cipher, so that when an adversary knows $n$ many cleartexts and their corresponding ciphertexts, he is not able to use them in $n$ many equations to get the key (one of the variables, which is then used to decrypt the rest of the ciphertext).  I wonder if it is possible to have encryption using operations that effectively require more and more equations as we add more equations.  E.g. say we require $2$ equations, but as we add the second, the second itself requires $2$ more (so becomes $4$) so we never make it.

Comment: Hm. I'd be surprised if there wasn't any work on this already, but I have no real knowledge of cryptography research. It's probably possible (replace "linear dependence" by "algebraic dependence" in the usual constructions, and use families of polynomials), but I don't know off the top of my head how to make it happen. If you want to go that way, I really highly recommend reading a good textbook on Computer Algebra, just to know all the algorithms you will need.